cannot play radio stations in apps or in browser after upgrading to Ubuntu 24:10 Missing plugin in Gstreamer
I cannot play radio stations in apps or in browser after upgrading to Ubuntu 24:10 Missing plugin in Gstreamer.
Browser is Firefox, app is Rhytmbox.
Both complain about missing plugin in gstreamer.
I cannot determine which plugin is missing.
I installed all available from the gstreamer website without any error. Rebooted the system but the problem still exist. This is happening on two different systems with the same version of Ubuntu. Before upgrade the radio stations could be played without out any problem with Firefox and Rhytmbox.
Who can offer a solution?

Is it just one radio station, or do none work?

@jos. Al radio stations won't work.

install from software>addons>codecs

Do you still have access to a computer with the previous O/S version?
if so, does it have 'gnome software' app installed.
If you do, and if the broken pc has 'gnome software' then open 'gnome software' and scroll to the bottom and pick 'codecs'.
The aim is to compare the codecs between the working and non-working pc's.
Hopefully that will help.

unfortunately i don't have an older version running. I will try  however to boot with a older version on a usb stick and will compare the codecs

@peteb I installed the missings codecs from software>codecs for QT6 and it is working again. Thanx

@LeenSpaans You may want to post that as an answer.
